# Reactive Extensions Test Scheduler Simulating Time elapse

Tags: c#, unit-testing, system.reactive

I am working with RX scheduler classes using the .Schedule(DateTimeOffset, Action>) stuff. Basically I've a scheduled action that can schedule itself again.

Code:

```
public SomeObject(IScheduler sch, Action variableAmountofTime)
{
    this.sch = sch;
    sch.Schedule(GetNextTime(), (Action<DateTimeOffset> runAgain =>
    {
        //Something that takes an unknown variable amount of time.
        variableAmountofTime();

        runAgain(GetNextTime());
    });
}

public DateTimeOffset GetNextTime()
{
    //Return some time offset based on scheduler's 
    //current time which is irregular based on other inputs that i have left out.
    return this.sch.now.AddMinutes(1);
}
```

My Question is concerning simulating the amount of time variableAmountofTime might take and testing that my code behaves as expected and only triggers calling it as expected.

I have tried advancing the test scheduler's time inside the delegate but that does not work. Example of code that I wrote that doesnt work. Assume GetNextTime() is just scheduleing one minute out.

```
[Test]
public void TestCallsAppropriateNumberOfTimes()
{
    var sch = new TestScheduler();

    var timesCalled = 0;

    var variableAmountOfTime = () => 
        { 
            sch.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3).Ticks); 
            timescalled++; 
        };

    var someObject = new SomeObject(sch, variableAmountOfTime);

    sch.AdvanceTo(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3).Ticks);

    Assert.That(timescalled, Is.EqualTo(1));
}
```

Since I am wanting to go 3 minutes into the future but the execution takes 3 minutes, I want to see this only trigger 1 time..instead it triggers 3 times.

How can I simulate something taking time during execution using the test scheduler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question. Unfortunately, this is **currently not supported** in Rx v1.x and Rx v2.0 Beta (**but read on**). Let me explain the complication of nested Advance* calls to you.

Basically, Advance* implies starting the scheduler to run work till the point specified. This involves running the work in order on a single logical thread that represents the flow of time in the virtual scheduler. Allowing nested Advance* calls raises a few questions.

First of all, should a nested Advance* call cause a nested worker loop to be run? If that were the case, we're no longer mimicking a single logical thread of execution as the current work item would be interrupted in favor of running the inner loop. In fact, Advance* would lead to an implicit yield where the rest of the work (that was due now) after the Advance* call would not be allowed to run until all nested work has been processed. This leads to the situation where future work cannot depend on (or wait for) past work to finish its execution. One way out is to introduce real physical concurrency, which defeats various design points of the virtual time and historical schedulers to begin with.

Alternatively, should a nested Advance* call somehow communicate to the top-most worker loop dispatching call (Advance* or Start) it may need to extend its due time because a nested invocation has asked to advance to a point beyond the original due time. Now all sorts of things are getting weird though. The clock doesn't reflect the changes after returning from Advance* and the top-most call no longer finishes at a predictable time.

For **Rx v2.0 RC** (coming next month), we took a look at this scenario and decided Advance* is not the right thing to emulate "time slippage" because it'd need an overloaded meaning depending on the context where it's invoked from. Instead, we're introducing a **Sleep method** that can be used to slip time forward from any context, without the side-effect of running work. Think of it as a way to set the Clock property but with safeguarding against going back in time. The name also reflects the intent clearly.

In addition to the above, to reduce the surprise factor of nested Advance* calls having no effect, we made it detect this situation and throw an **InvalidOperationException** in a nested context. Sleep, on the other hand, can be called from anywhere.

One final note. It turns out we needed exactly the same feature for work we're doing in Rx v2.0 RC with regards to our treatment of time. Several tests required a deterministic way to emulate slippage of time due to the execution of user code that can take arbitrarily long (think of the OnNext handler to e.g. Observable.Interval).

Hope this helps... Stay tuned for our Rx v2.0 RC release in the next few weeks!

-Bart (Rx team)

Comment: Thanks Bart! I appreciate the response.

Comment: Is there a way to determine whether the scheduler is already running?